# how can measure the benchmark in linux

Tags: apache, nginx, benchmarking

I installed `phoronix-test-suite` on my Centos with 2.6.32-504.23.4.el6.x86_64 kernel
and I want to benchmark Nginx and Apache web servers.

I ran `phoronix-test-suite benchmark pts/apache` and I got the following result:

```
Apache Benchmark 2.4.7:
    pts/apache-1.6.1
    Test 1 of 1
    Estimated Trial Run Count:    3
    Estimated Time To Completion: 9 Minutes
        Running Pre-Test Script @ 14:21:20
        Started Run 1 @ 14:21:25
        Started Run 2 @ 14:24:36
        Started Run 3 @ 14:27:25  [Std. Dev: 7.14%]
        Started Run 4 @ 14:30:15  [Std. Dev: 6.37%]
        Started Run 5 @ 14:33:01  [Std. Dev: 5.84%]
        Started Run 6 @ 14:36:03  [Std. Dev: 5.76%]
        Running Post-Test Script @ 14:39:08

    Test Results:
        5329.74
        6048.09
        6048.02
        6132.58
        5659.47
        5514.46

    Average: 5788.73 Requests Per Second
```

What are these numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

phoronix makes an `ab` stress testing against your apache, and that test takes to him 9 minutes and he did 6 test.

```
    5329.74
    6048.09
    6048.02
    6132.58
    5659.47
    5514.46
```

Those numbers are the request per second over each test

```
Average: 5788.73 Requests Per Second
```

that is the average for all test.

Comment: Tnx for your response !

Comment: if you know a good ref please suggest me ! 
i want to measure the performance in various condition for mysql